# How do I nest this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document from a web service that I am trying to query. However, I am not sure how to query the XML when it has elements nested inside other elements.

Here is a section of the XML file (I haven't included all of it because it's a long file):

```
<response>
    <display_location>
        <full>London, United Kingdom</full>
        <city>London</city>
        <state/>
        <state_name>United Kingdom</state_name>
        <country>UK</country>
        <country_iso3166>GB</country_iso3166>
        <zip>00000</zip>
        <magic>553</magic>
        <wmo>03772</wmo>
        <latitude>51.47999954</latitude>
        <longitude>-0.44999999</longitude>
        <elevation>24.00000000</elevation>
    </display_location>
    <observation_location>
        <full>London,</full>
        <city>London</city>
        <state/>
        <country>UK</country>
        <country_iso3166>GB</country_iso3166>
        <latitude>51.47750092</latitude>
        <longitude>-0.46138901</longitude>
        <elevation>79 ft</elevation>
    </observation_location>
```

I can query "one section at a time" but I'm constructing an object from the LINQ. For example:

```
var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("display_location")
           select new Forecast
           {
               DisplayFullName = i.Element("full").Value
           };

var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("observation_location")
           select new Forecast
           {
               ObservationFullName = i.Element("full").Value
           };
```

And my "Forecast" class is basically just full of properties like this:

```
class Forecast
{
    public string DisplayFullName { get; set; };
    public string ObservationFullName { get; set; };
    //Lots of other properties that will be set from the XML
}
```

However, I need to "combine" all of the LINQ together so that I can set all the properties of the object. I have read about nested LINQ but I do not know how to apply it to this particular case.

Question: How do I go about "nesting/combining" the LINQ so that I can read the XML and then set the appropriate properties with said XML?

Comment: What exactly do you need to combine? The LINQ queries or the query results?

Comment: I'm not sure, which ever one that would ultimately allow me to set the properties of the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way :

```
var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("response")
           select new Forecast
           {
               DisplayFullName = (string)i.Element("display_location").Element("full"),
               ObservationFullName = (string)i.Element("observation_location").Element("full")
           };
```

Comment: This is in interesting idea, I didn't know you could keep using .Element to retrieve data. However, this throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: That can happen if any `<response>` element doesn't have `<display_location>` or `<observation_location>` child element. Can you confirm that is the case/not the case?

Comment: It does have these, see here: http://api.wunderground.com/api/d36f54198ebbb48c/conditions/q/England/London.xml

Comment: Oh wait, I think I forgot about the "current_observation" tag. Do you happen to know how I would incorporate that into the query you wrote?

Comment: yup, try to replace `Descendants("response")` with `Descendants("current_observation")`

Comment: That no longer throws the exception thanks! It is indeed retrieving the "display_location" part which has "London, United Kingdom" in it but it gets an empty string for the "observation_location" which should have "London," in it.

Comment: are you sure no typo? I tested using above URL in your comment and I got "London," here... worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Another way ... I prefer using the Linq extension methods in fluent style

```
var results = weatherResponse.Descendants()
.SelectMany(d => d.Elements())
.Where(e => e.Name == "display_location" || e.Name == "observation_location")
.Select(e => 
    {
        if(e.Name == "display_location")
        {
            return new ForeCast{  DisplayFullName = e.Element("full").Value };
        }
        else if(e.Name == "observation_location")
        {
            return new ForeCast{  ObservationFullName = e.Element("full").Value };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    });
```